# React useEffect hook running infinite loop despite static dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

Can someone please point to me what part of this code is causing an infinite loop?
I have tried wrapping this in useCallback as well but it still runs forever.

- slug is the page url that will not change over time
- likesCollectionRef is also goint to remain constant
- isAuth can change overtime depending on if the user is logged in or out

```
export default function CommentForm({ slug, isAuth, setReloadTS }) {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);

  const likesCollectionRef = collection(fireStore, 'likes');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuth) return;

    const qry = query(
      likesCollectionRef,
      where('slug', '==', slug),
      where('author.id', '==', auth.currentUser.uid)
    );

    const findLike = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(qry);
      console.log(`initial like: ${data.docs}`);
      setIsLiked(data.docs !== 'undefined' && data.docs);
    };

    findLike();
  }, [slug, isAuth, likesCollectionRef]);
}
```

Comment: If the only changing piece is "isAuth" then why add the other ones as deps? also it is clear that some deps are changing otherwise why would it be executing more than once.....

Comment: Dependencies other than "isAuth" are added merely to satisfy the linter. No dependencies are really changing including isAuth, the infinite loop can be observed immediately at page load.

Comment: useEffect executes when a dependency changes so 100% sure one of your deps is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`likesCollectionRef` is declared each render cycle. Place the likes collection reference in a React ref so it's a stable reference. `auth` also appears to be an external dependency. If it's external to the component this is ok, but if it's internal to the component it should be added to the dependency array.

```
export default function CommentForm({ slug, isAuth, setReloadTS }) {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);

  const likesCollectionRef = useref(collection(fireStore, 'likes'));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuth) return;

    const qry = query(
      likesCollectionRef.current,
      where('slug', '==', slug),
      where('author.id', '==', auth.currentUser.uid)
    );

    const findLike = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(qry);
      console.log(`initial like: ${data.docs}`);
      setIsLiked(data.docs !== 'undefined' && data.docs);
    };

    findLike();
  }, [isAuth, likesCollectionRef, slug]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: That was it, created a reference for likesCollectionRef. Although auth is an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: @DeepakKapoor `auth` is? Ok, I'll remove that part of my answer.